# Python: comparing nested values - neater method

Tags: python, performance, for-in-loop

I'm new to python **know** there is a better way to do this extremely simple task but I dont seem to be asking the right questions and I am hoping someone here can give me some advice on how to neaten up my code - I feel like I am writing way to much code to do what I am doing.

I'm tagging my recorded tv shows with tvdb_api. The api returns the banners in an interesting structure (dict nesting tuples nesting dicts) the basic structure is:

```
{"684x400":
    {"949520":
        {"_bannerpath": "http://tvdb.com/banners/somepath",
         "rating" : 9.000
         #etc...
        },
     "456520":
        {"_bannerpath": "http://tvdb.com/banners/somepath",
            "rating" : 9.000
            #and so on...
        }
    }
}
```

I loop over the items in the data structure, compare the `rating` values and get the `_bannerpath` of the highest rated banner. I do this by getting all of the `rating` and `_bannerpath` values from the structure and copying them into as nested lists into a list and then seperating out the rating values into another list and using max to get the highest value and returning the corresponding bannerpath!

There **MUST** be a better way than this!

```
posterList = []

for tup in bannerStructure:
            for key in tup[1]:
                    if key == "rating":
                            posterList.append([tup[1]['rating'],tup[1]['_bannerpath']])
        ratingList = []

        for rating in posterList:
            ratingList.append(rating[0])

        maxRating = max(ratingList)

        for lst in posterList:
            if lst[0] == maxRating:
                return lst[1]
```

thankyou for your help!

Comment: do you want to get `_bannerpath` with the highest `rating` for each `nxm` resolution?

Comment: You can [a] sort by the rating with `sorted`, or [b] keep a running max in your loop.

Comment: The sample data you've posted is not a valid python data structure.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary apologies J.F.Sebastian was correct updating question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the actual structure is like this:

```
{"684x400":
    {"949520":
        {"_bannerpath": "http://tvdb.com/banners/somepath",
         "rating" : 9.000
         #etc...
        },
     "456520":
        {"_bannerpath": "http://tvdb.com/banners/somepath",
         "rating" : 9.000
         #and so on...
        }
    }
}
```

Then to find a banner with the highest rating for each resolution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for resolution, banners in tvdb_api_result.items():
    bannerpath = max(banners.values(), key=itemgetter('rating'))['_bannerpath']
    print("%s %s" % (resolution, bannerpath))
```

Comment: @leemo: make sure that `rating` is indeed a float in the input otherwise the comparison will be incorrect e.g., `"2" > "10"`. You could use: `key=lambda b: float(b['rating'])` to parse it to get `2 < 10`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension and `max` function to get this

```
max([(k["_bannerpath"], k["rating"]) for v in data.values() for k in v.values()], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Comment: elegant. +1 I will experiement with this method also... the Python docs dont work well with my brain unfortunately... are you about to briefly explain the function of lambda